# DynamoDB Python: Creating an item and add it to existing table

Tags: python, json, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to add an item to an existing table in DynamoDB, however, I keep getting the error message

> missing the key humidity in the item

when running the program. The raw JSON data is [here](https://pastebin.com/UCp9JtEy) My code to create the **item** is below.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal

# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if abs(o) % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1', endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")

table = dynamodb.Table('Machines')

machinekey = 1
city = "Miami"
state = "Florida"

response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'machinekey': machinekey,
        'city': city,
        'state': state,
        'machinevals': {
            'machineid': 1,
            'date': "01/03/2019",
            'humidity': 25,
            'pressure': 105
        }
    }
)

print("PutItem succeeded:")
print(json.dumps(response, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

My code to create the table is below.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1', endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")


table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Machines',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'humidity',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Sort key, not partition (HASH)
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'pressure',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'humidity',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'pressure',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },

    ]
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)

print("Table status:", table.table_status)
```

I've been following Step 1 provided on [AWS's website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html) by creating a similar JSON structure and replacing variables in their example provided.

Comment: Does the fact that humidity is nested inside another value mean anything?  Should the humidity in your schema be represented as such?

Comment: What is your hash and sort keys? Do you have any local secondary index?

Comment: @T.Gerdy Yes, I'm trying to show machine outputs during various days. Each day must have the machine ID, date, peak humidity recorded, and peak pressure recorded.

Comment: @erencan I don't have any local secondary index.

Answer (score 0):

Your Range and Hash keys need to be in the root of your Item structure...

```
response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'machinekey': machinekey,
        'city': city,
        'state': state,
        'humidity': 25,
        'pressure': 105
        'machinevals': {
            'machineid': 1,
            'date': "01/03/2019"
        }
    }
)
```

If you want those values to also be in machinevals you could always duplicate them in there, but your hash and range key need to be in the root.

You could also try defining your hash and range keys as machinevals:humidity and machinevals:pressure but I am not sure that would work...